# Size of flex item is changed when I increase window's size on Chrome

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I have a trouble when using flex box CSS, hope everyone help me. Flex item make text drop when responsive.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ2L9.png)

It's ok when window's size down and only Chrome get this trouble.

```css
.career-nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.career-nav a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.428em;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #000;
    padding: 13px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background .2s ease;
}
```

```html
<ul class="career-nav">
  <li><a href="#Citya" title="A City">City A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Cityb" title="Hanoi">City B</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Cityc" title="Danang">City C</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `flex-wrap: wrap;` make the flexible items wrap if necessary. https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap

Comment: @Smollet777 thank you but it still dropping down, text "City A" is dropping down only window size changed, I do something it's working well (ex: delete anything line of code)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are leaving your nav link with a default flex behaviour.

I would try to add a "flex" attribute to the links, at the same time it will be useful to set "nowrap" behaviour to the container

```
 .career-nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
 .career-nav a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.428em;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #000;
    padding: 13px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background .2s ease;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
 }
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fbxq74rw/

Tested on Chrome, Firefox and Safari

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but it is not working, original item size is 52 pixels, after I changed window's size, it had gotten down size. On firefox is ok

Comment: Solved, try the fiddle. You have to be more specific on your flex setting for links. with `flex: 0 0 auto` you are basically saying that they will not shrink or grow, space available will be shared only by `justify-content: space-around;`

Comment: I would like to know why my answer was downvoted and from who.... Just to understand what he suggest as an alternative..

Comment: I'm sorry about that,  I don't know who did it. I'm very glad for your help, I think new chrome update had some problem for code, because I used to make that before and nothing like that

Comment: Have you tried my last update, I tested the fiddle on Chrome, Firefox and Safari